# R doesn't allow me to define the number of columns I want my header to spawn

Tags: r, header, string-formatting, kable

I made a R-script and build several html tables with kablExtra. I made 4 tables. I forgot to make a header for the 3th. So I tried to make a header for the third with this code:

```
#### Set GLOBAL options ####
options(knitr.table.format = "html")

# make headers
main_icc_title <- c("Table 3: Intraclass Correlation coefficients between AVA 3.2"^"\u00AE"*" and CytoCamTools "^"\u00AE"*"." = 3)
main_icc_title_spec <- c(0,3)
    
  # Build the html table
    table_3 <- main_icc_table %>%
      kbl(col.names = c("Variable", "ICC [95% CI]", "Agreement"), align = "lll", row.names = FALSE) %>%
      kable_styling("striped") %>%
      column_spec(1, bold = TRUE, width = "10em") %>%
      column_spec(2, width = "10em") %>%
      column_spec(3, width = "10em") %>%
      kable_paper("hover", full_widt = F, position = "center") %>%
      add_header_above(main_icc_title, main_icc_title_spec) %>%
      footnote(general_title = "",  general = "Intraclass Correlations Coefficients were calculated for each variable using a two-way mixed effects model for single rater and absolute agreement. Confidence intervals and interpretation of agreement are given for each variable. ICC: intraclass correlation coeficient, CI: confidence interval.")
```

But suddenly I got the error:

```
main_icc_title <- c("Table 3: Intraclass Correlation coefficients between AVA 3.2"^"\u00AE"*" and CytoCamTools"^"\u00AE"*"." = 3)
Error: unexpected '=' in "     main_icc_title <- c("Table 3: Intraclass Correlation coefficients between AVA 3.2"^"\u00AE"*" and CytoCamTools"^"\u00AE"*"." ="
```

I removed the =, but then ofcourse it doesn't spawn the right amount of columns. But suddenly R also stopped accepting `^"\u00AE"*`.

```
Error in "Table 3: Intraclass Correlation coefficients between AVA 3.2"^"®" : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The weirdest thing is. Now table 4, which was working perfectly fine, gets the same errors. While Table 1 and 2 work perfectly fine...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: your line defining `main_icc_title <-` is not valid R syntax. If I simplify the strings it's basically `main_icc_title <- c("a" ^ "b" * "c" ^ "d" * "e" = 3)` which doesn't make sense to R. What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to created a named vector? Or just define one long string? It's not very clear what that line is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I try to make one long string. Which should fucntion as an header. This =3 statement at the end is needed to span it over all three columns of my table. I went debugging and found out that the problem is combination of ^\u00A3* and the =3. If I leave those superscript special characters out it prints the header as I want.

Comment: Are you looking for `paste0` perhaps? Or do you want the `"` marks around e.g. `^` and `*` to be included in your string, then you can use single quotes (`'`) around the string. Perhaps you can clarify what the string should be, and why you are trying to build it this way.